# How to create a tuple of ranges?

Tags: d

```d
template tupIndexToRange(alias Tup, Indicies...){
  import std.meta;
  import std.typecons;
  static if(Indicies.length == 0){
    enum tupIndexToRange = tuple();
  }
  else{
    enum tupIndexToRange = tuple(Tup[ Indicies[0] ][], tupIndexToRange!(Tup,Indicies[1..$]));
  }
}

void main(){
  alias Integrals = AliasSeq!(Array!int, Array!float, Array!double);
  Tuple!Integrals integrals;
  integrals[0].insertBack(1);
  integrals[1].insertBack(2);
  integrals[2].insertBack(3);
  auto t = tupIndexToRange!(integrals, 0, 1, 2);
  auto r = zip(t.expand);
}
```

err:

```
source/app.d(119,34): Error: variable integrals cannot be read at compile time
source/app.d(119,33):        called from here: tuple(integrals.__expand_field_2.opSlice(), Tuple())
source/app.d(119,56): Error: template instance app.main.tupIndexToRange!(integrals, 2) error instantiating
source/app.d(119,56):        instantiated from here: tupIndexToRange!(integrals, 1, 2)
source/app.d(219,12):        instantiated from here: tupIndexToRange!(integrals, 0, 1, 2)
```

I assume this error appears because I am trying to access the range at compile time? How would I tell D that I only need to access the range at run time?

This is what `tupIndexToRange` should do:

```d
auto t = tuple(integrals[0][], integrals[1][], integrals[2][]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would I tell D that I only need to access the range at run time?

By passing it as a runtime parameter:

```
template tupIndexToRange(Indicies...) {
    auto tupIndexToRange(T)(T tup) {
      static if(Indicies.length == 0){
        return tuple();
      }
      else{
        return tuple(tup[ Indicies[0] ][], .tupIndexToRange!(Indicies[1..$])(tup).expand);
      }
    }
}
```

Two things to note:

1. The function nested in the template allows us to just specify the indices and not the type. If it were just `auto tupIndexToRange(T, Indices)(T tup)`, we woul have to provide the type explicitly.
2. We recurse by calling `.tupIndexToRange` rather than `tupIndexToRange`, as we want to recurse via the template in the outer scope, not the nested function.

Comment: Though it should in theory be possible to use the alias ... I'm curious to see if someone comes up with a solution for that.